Create a canvas with mirrored edges

Hey there, I am trying to reproduce the effect of the above picture : mirrored edges.
What I've done is :

Having a photograph mirrored on the edges (the black part represent the initial picture, the white part the mirrored part)



I've put the UVs on my canvas like this :


Now the problem is that I have a weird deformation on the sides.

While it works on the front

I don't know how to solve this issue, maybe some of you have run into similar issues ?
Thank you,

This sounds like the "aligning brickwork round a corner" problem which Ryan King demonstrates in his series on creating an industrial building. The section on texturing starts here and the part about aligning the texture starts here.

Eventually I found a workaround.
No need for having the mirrored edges directly in the picture, just using this setup and making sure the left & right planes have UVs mirrored on the X axis, and up & down planes UVs mirrored on the Y axis, will work

